# How to make the green DIV fit right after 2 upper divs?

Tags: html, css

What can I do in order for the dark green div (Inner3) to be right after (under) the blue and pink divs (Inner1 and Inner2 respectively)?. Currently there is some kind of "space".

Note: I put the orange div on purpose after them and only then the green one, the formation does matter (I'm trying to learn how to change css when changing resolutions on media query).

```css
.OuterDiv {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #E3EAD7;
  height: 100%;
}
.Inner1 {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #6D97C0;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.Inner2 {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #ECB7D8;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.Inner3 {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #F5E6AD;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
}
.Inner4 {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #728666;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="OuterDiv">
    <div class="Inner1"></div>
    <div class="Inner2"></div>
    <div class="Inner3"></div>
    <div class="Inner4"></div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: so you want blue and pink div in line as they are then the green div and then the yellowish div that too without changing html structure?

Comment: modify your last div as this 

.Inner4 {
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #728666;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top : -100px;
}

add position : relative;
add top : -100px;

Comment: the problem is since the div is a block level element it will never let any other element to be on the same line so your 3rd div have 300px which is going to push your green div 100px down so you either can fix this as I told you or decreasing the height of the yellow div to 200px instead of 300px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just changed the following:

```
.Inner3 {
 ...
  float:right;
}
```

and it worked like a charm.

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rkdm2711/)

Comment: Genius. didn't think about it. How is possible? :) can you explain why it works? (i do understand that it goes to the right... but what about the ones who go to the left?). Thank you again!

Comment: i would like to refer to the article [css floats](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-floats/) . Just remember that float only affects the elements which are **placed after the floated element** in the code. Hence to place the orange to right (or green to left) you cannot apply float to the last(green) div. Hence we apply `float:right` to the orange div.

Comment: Can you please explain the last comment? didn't quite understand. thanks!

Comment: here's a nice tutorial to try and clear your concepts [reference](http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101) . But I'll try to explain as much as i can in another answer...

Answer (score 0):

You need to change html structure to achieve such behaviour. 
Other type of solutions (giving negative margin to Inner4 etc) is not nice.

```css
.OuterDiv {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #E3EAD7;
  height: 100%;
}
.Inner1 {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #6D97C0;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.Inner2 {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #ECB7D8;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.Inner3 {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #F5E6AD;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
}
.Inner4 {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #728666;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="OuterDiv">
    <div>
      <div class="Inner1"></div>
      <div class="Inner2"></div>
      <div class="Inner4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Inner3"></div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `position:relative` to `.inner3` and `.inner4` then handling them with margin's and top property

```css
.OuterDiv {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #E3EAD7;
  height: 100%;
}
.Inner1 {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #6D97C0;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.Inner2 {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #ECB7D8;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.Inner3 {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #F5E6AD;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
}
.Inner4 {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #728666;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: -300px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="OuterDiv">
    <div class="Inner1"></div>
    <div class="Inner2"></div>
    <div class="Inner3"></div>
    <div class="Inner4"></div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If change the order of inner3 to 4 and 4 to 3 it will work

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<style type="text/css">.OuterDiv {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #E3EAD7;
  height: 100%;
}
.Inner1 {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #6D97C0;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.Inner2 {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #ECB7D8;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.Inner3 {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #F5E6AD;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
}
.Inner4 {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #728666;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="OuterDiv">
    <div class="Inner1"></div>
    <div class="Inner2"></div>
    <div class="Inner4"></div>
    <div class="Inner3"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The idea was not to change the order :) I'm trying to learn how to change classes on @media different sizes and trying to see what happens if I need to take a div and somehow positioned it otherwise. The example I posted is a possible scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code, this get's your **green div right (under or below) the blue and pink**. So, at top we have **blue,pink** and **right below that green**. You can even **remove orange** from your html code, if you want but at that stage remove set margin-top back to margin 0 of .Inner4.

```
.Inner3 {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #F5E6AD;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
  float:left;
}
.Inner4 {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #728666;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="block pink "></div>
<div class="block blue "></div>
<div class="block green"></div>
<div class="block orange"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.floatLeft {
  float: left;
}

.floatRight {
  float: right;
}

.pink {
  background: #ee3e64;
}

.blue {
  background: #44accf;
}

.green {
  background: #b7d84b;
}

.orange {
  background: #E2A741;
}
```

**Case 1: Without any float**

[Case 1](https://jsfiddle.net/yb4xo9p6/)

**Case 2: only pink floated left**

The pink comes out of flow and floats left, rest all divs are present as if pink is absent(since blue, green and orange are not floated). Hence blue is below pink.

[Case 2](https://jsfiddle.net/yb4xo9p6/1/)

**Case 3: only blue floated left**

Since float only affects the divs after the floated div, hence pink remains as it was in Case 1. And blue gets floated left. green and orange are as if there is no blue.

[Case 3](https://jsfiddle.net/yb4xo9p6/2/)

**Case 4: only green floated left**

[Case 4](https://jsfiddle.net/yb4xo9p6/3/)

Check for yourself.

**Case 5: only pink floated right**

pink is floated right, and out of flow. Others are as if pink is absent.

[Case 5](https://jsfiddle.net/yb4xo9p6/4/)

**Case 6: only blue floated right**

pink unaffected since floated div (blue) is after it (in HTML structure). Blue is floated right and out of flow. green and orange are as if blue is absent.

[Case 6](https://jsfiddle.net/yb4xo9p6/5/)

**Case 7: only green floated right**

pink and blue are unaffected since floating green is after them. green is floated right and out of flow. orange is as if green is absent.

[Case 7](https://jsfiddle.net/yb4xo9p6/6/)

**Case 8: pink->float left, blue->float right**

Observe now that both the pink and the blue are out of flow. Hence the green and orange are present as if there is no pink or blue. But due to float the pink is above green.

[Case 8](https://jsfiddle.net/yb4xo9p6/7/)

**Case 9: pink->float right, blue->float left**

Again, observe that both the pink and the blue are out of flow. Hence the green and orange are present as if there is no pink or blue. But due to float the blue is above green.

[Case 9](https://jsfiddle.net/yb4xo9p6/8/)

**Case 10: pink->float right, green->float left**

Just inspect-element on any web-browser and see for yourself the positions of the divisions. That way you'll understand better.

[Case 10](https://jsfiddle.net/yb4xo9p6/9/)

Now you can experiment on your own and better understand the concept of floats :)

Your question was similar to:

[Demo 1](https://jsfiddle.net/yb4xo9p6/11/)

Here the difference is that all divs have the attribute **overflow: hidden** . This ensures that green is not hidden under pink as in :

[Demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/yb4xo9p6/12/)

and I just changed [Demo 1](https://jsfiddle.net/yb4xo9p6/11/) to (my solution):

[Demo 3](https://jsfiddle.net/yb4xo9p6/13/)